# What is a better way to organize WPF elements?

Tags: wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I have the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.Window2" ...
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- 0: Row Zero -->
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <!-- 1: Row 1 -->
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <!-- 2: Row 2 -->
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            ...
            <!-- and so on. -->

       <!-- 0: Row Zero elements -->
       <Label Grid.Row="0" ... />
       <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" ... />

       <!-- 1: Row 1 elements -->
       <Label Grid.Row="1" ... />
       <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" ... />
...
```

At design time, if I have to insert a row, say between row 0 and row 1, I then have to renumber the `Grid.Row` attached properties for all the `Label` and `TextBlock` elements because now they are all shifted by plus one.

Is there an easier way of doing this so that I can just insert a row and not have to adjust the remaining items below that row?

Comment: If you only have a single column, consider using `StackPanel`. Also, avoid setting explicit width and height values on elements. In `Grid` layouts always prefer `Auto` and Fractional width/height values where possible.

Comment: @Dai I have two columns, but the relative location of the column elements stay fixed (zero and 1), so that is not a problem. If you have the time, I would be interested in your detailed answer.

Comment: I'll disappoint you now :) unfortunately there is no way to use WPF's Grid without manually setting the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties on each constituent control.

Comment: @dai Thank you for following up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, there's no way to do this directly with `Grid`. You'll have to reflow the indices manually unfortunately.

Another option, if this is really important to you, is to create a custom panel and use some non-visual child element as row separators. Internally that panel could still use a `Grid` to position its children, and it would have to set the `Grid.Row` and/or `Grid.Column` attached property values itself.

Comment: Drew, thank you. If you have the time, I would appreciate getting more detail on the use of non-visual child elements as row separators. If you'd like, I can post a separate question for that and let you know.